# How could I check - does my SQLite3 database is empty?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am using Python 2.7 and SQLite3.
When I starting work with DB I want to check - does my database is empty or on not. I mean does it already have any tables or not.

My idea is to use the simple SELECT from any table. And wrap this select in try:exception block. So if exception was raised then my DB is empty.

Maybe someone know the better way for checking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SELECT name FROM sqlite_master`

while connected to your database will give you all the tables names. you can then do a fetchall and check the size, or even contents of the list. not try/catch necessary (the list will be empty if the database doesn't contain any tables)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but I prefer to use the [`user_version`](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_user_version) for the purpose of efficiently sanity-checking my database. Whenever I create a DB I set the `user_version` to a non-zero value (generally starting with `1` and incrementing as I make breaking changes to the schema) alongside my `CREATE TABLE` calls and associated bootstrapping. This helps me know not only that my DB is not empty but also that it's initialized as I expect. If the `user_version` is different than expected I can return an error or apply a schema migration to the supported version.

Obviously this only works for DBs you created/own. If you're trying to inspect the contents of an arbitrary DB `sqlite_master` is the way to go.